# multiprocessing.Process - why doesn't the .start() method work in the IDLE console?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing 

def simple():
    print 'simple!'

p0 = multiprocessing.Process(target=simple)
p0.start()
```

This doesn't do anything apparently. AFAIK it should print "simple!".
I'm writing all this code inside the interactive console.

[EDIT] Could the other process not be connected to this terminal? if so, can I do something to connect it to the same  terminal?

Comment: `simple` should be importable from your source file. You need to put `p0 = ...` and the next line inside of a `if __name__ == '__main__'` block to prevent Python from going into an infinite loop.

Comment: I actually managed to make this work by importing the modules. The question is regarding the console. It's there that this doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDLE redirects standard output and input in various odd ways. Therefore, it not uncommon for something not to work in IDLE. I just tried your code, and it runs fine in SL4A. Try running it outside of IDLE. I can say that is probably going to work. Bottom line: It is just the way IDLE does things. Sorry! Try another IDE, like PyScripter or Komodo Edit.

Comment: well my issue isn't making the code work in IDLE anyway, there's just where i'm testing quick pieces of code to write inside eclipse. It got me worried that there was somehow a mistake in my code cause the issue. Thx for the reply.

Comment: @vlad-ardelean: You're welcome! You could always just use the default Python shell. Good luck!

Comment: in the default shell, this raises `AttributeError`. "module 'object' has no attribute 'simple'".

Comment: @vlad-ardelean: According to the Python docs, multiprocessing cannot be
used from the shell, as it needs to be run from a module with an importable
main function. Read the introduction [docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html].